# C#: Test if an object implements any of a list of interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to test if a type implements one of a set of interfaces.

```
    ViewData["IsInTheSet"] =
            model.ImplementsAny<IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3, IInterface4>();
```

I have written the following extension methods to handle this.

Is there a more extensible way to write the following code? I would prefer not to have to write a new method while still leveraging generics.

```
    public static bool Implements<T>(this object obj)
    {
        Check.Argument.IsNotNull(obj, "obj");

        return (obj is T);
    }

    public static bool ImplementsAny<T>(this object obj)
    {
        return obj.Implements<T>();
    }

    public static bool ImplementsAny<T,V>(this object obj)
    {
        if (Implements<T>(obj))
            return true;
        if (Implements<V>(obj))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ImplementsAny<T,V,W>(this object obj)
    {
        if (Implements<T>(obj))
            return true;
        if (Implements<V>(obj))
            return true;
        if (Implements<W>(obj))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ImplementsAny<T, V, W, X>(this object obj)
    {
        if (Implements<T>(obj))
            return true;
        if (Implements<V>(obj))
            return true;
        if (Implements<W>(obj))
            return true;
        if (Implements<X>(obj))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is perhaps a better question for http://s.tk/review.

Comment: Store `Type` objects via `typeof(InterfaceN)` and then use the `obj.GetType()` and determine relationships that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use something like the following:

```
public static bool ImplementsAny(this object obj, params Type[] types)
{
    foreach(var type in types)
    {
        if(type.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
model.ImplementsAny(typeof(IInterface1),
                    typeof(IInterface2),
                    typeof(IInterface3),
                    typeof(IInterface4));
```

Comment: Be careful when using `Type.IsAssignableFrom` to determine if the type implements the interface; it doesn't work for situations where the `obj` is a generic class. I found out this the hard way, so it's been handled by the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I check if an interface has been implemented is:

```
public static bool IsImplementationOf(this Type checkMe, Type forMe)
{
    if (forMe.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        return checkMe.GetInterfaces().Select(i =>
        {
            if (i.IsGenericType)
                return i.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            return i;
        }).Any(i => i == forMe);

    return forMe.IsAssignableFrom(checkMe);
}
```

This could be easily extended to:

```
public static bool IsImplementationOf(this Type checkMe, params Type[] forUs)
{
    return forUs.Any(forMe =>
    {
        if (forMe.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            return checkMe.GetInterfaces().Select(i =>
            {
                if (i.IsGenericType)
                    return i.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

                return i;
            }).Any(i => i == forMe);

        return forMe.IsAssignableFrom(checkMe);
    });
}
```

Or better yet:

```
public static bool IsImplementationOf(this Type checkMe, params Type[] forUs)
{
    return forUs.Any(forMe => checkMe.IsImplementationOf(forMe));
}
```

*Warning: Untested*

Then just do a `typeof` on your type parameters before passing them to this.